# How to add spaces in txt file

Tags: shell, command, sh

I wan to add particular number of spaces in text file.
Please consider below example for more details.

suppose my file contains

```
amrutdange  
mkdange
```

in above file first row contains 10 character and second row contains 7 character.

Expected output : 
I want every row in file is having 15 character i.e for first row I want 10 character which are already present in file and 5 spaces after that and for second row 7 character plus 8 spaces .

So file data will look like

```
amrutdange + 5 spaces  
mkdange    + 7 spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` with `printf` will do the job:

```
awk '{printf "%-15s\n", $0}' file
```

To verify:

```
awk '{printf "%-15s\n", $0}' file | cat -vte
amrutdange     $
mkdange        $
```

PS: If you want fields longer than 15 characters to be truncated to 15 then use:

```
printf "%-15.15s\n", $0
```

Comment: :can you please explain this? How it will work . it will be great help for me

Comment: It is actually `printf` that does the formatting. `%-15s` makes every field 15 in length and `-` after `%` makes output left aligned.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.